# Passar o valor de uma key ao criar ou após criado o array

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho o seguinte arquivo JSON:

```js
const animais = {"types":[
  {
    "id":100196,
    "animal":"dog",
    "type":"adult",
    "tags":"AA 96 87"
  },{
    "objid":100578,
    "animal":"cat",
    "type":"old",
    "tags":"T2 96 AB"
  },{
    "objid":100643,
    "animal":"parrot",
    "type":"young",
    "tags":"MAN L5 65"
  },{
    "objid":101165,
    "animal":"falcon",
    "type":"teen",
    "tags":"T2 56 AA"
  },{
    "objid":101168,
    "animal":"rabbit",
    "type":"old",
    "tags":"FII R25 75"
  },{
    "objid":164713,
    "animal":"rabbit",
    "type":"teen",
    "tags":"MAN R25 75"
  },{
    "objid":101174,
    "animal":"horse",
    "type":"baby",
    "tags":"MAN R62 75"
  },{
    "objid":101177,
    "animal":"turtle",
    "type":"old",
    "tags":"MAN R4 75"
  },{
    "objid":101180,
    "animal":"tiger",
    "type":"young",
    "tags":"MAN R8 75"
  }
]}
```

O dado foi tratado para retornar os animais separados dentro de um mesmo array, possuindo somente o nome do animal e as tags que o mesmo carrega.

```js
const types = animais.types.reduce((animal, item) => {
    const val = item.animal;
    animal[val] = animal[val] || [];
    animal[val].push(item);
    return animal;
    },{}
)

threeanimals = Object.entries(types)
    .filter(([key, value]) => value.length < 3)
    .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, tags: value.map(({tags}) => tags) }))

console.log(threeanimals)
```

A tratativa me retorna uma Array de Objetos com uma key, que carrega o nome do animal e um array de tags, com as tags que o objeto possuia.

```js
[Object {key: "dog", tags: ["AA 96 87"]}, Object {key: "cat", tags: ["T2 96 AB"]}, …]
```

O que eu poderia fazer para além das tags e o nome do objeto como key, me fosse retornado por exemplo, o primeiro trecho do nome da tag como key da tag e o objid como value? Da seguinte forma:

```js
[Object {key: "dog", tags: ["AA": "100196"]}, Object {key: "cat", tags: ["T2": "100578"]}, …]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo minimo de como criar essa solução utilizando `map` em vez de `reducer`:

```js
const animais = {
  "types": [{
    "objid": 100196,
    "animal": "dog",
    "type": "adult",
    "tags": "AA 96 87"
  }, {
    "objid": 100578,
    "animal": "cat",
    "type": "old",
    "tags": "T2 96 AB"
  }, {
    "objid": 100643,
    "animal": "parrot",
    "type": "young",
    "tags": "MAN L5 65"
  }, {
    "objid": 101165,
    "animal": "falcon",
    "type": "teen",
    "tags": "T2 56 AA"
  }, {
    "objid": 101168,
    "animal": "rabbit",
    "type": "old",
    "tags": "FII R25 75"
  }, {
    "objid": 164713,
    "animal": "rabbit",
    "type": "teen",
    "tags": "MAN R25 75"
  }, {
    "objid": 101174,
    "animal": "horse",
    "type": "baby",
    "tags": "MAN R62 75"
  }, {
    "objid": 101177,
    "animal": "turtle",
    "type": "old",
    "tags": "MAN R4 75"
  }, {
    "objid": 101180,
    "animal": "tiger",
    "type": "young",
    "tags": "MAN R8 75"
  }]
}

const types = animais.types.map((obj, index) => {      
  const tags = obj.tags.split(' ');
  return {
    key: obj.animal,
    tags: {
      [tags[0]]: obj.objid
    }
  };
}, {})

console.log(types);
```